# HTTP Completion Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-web-api

I'm getting an error "**Can't convert from int to system.net.http.httpcompletionoption.**"

I'm new to building Web APIs, and I'm just trying to make a simple GET request that takes in an int id and goes to my get method in my API which takes an int and returns the product with that id. I will post my code below and also where I'm getting the error at.

```
 public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        Contact contact = new Contact();
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:56194/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
//Im getting error on line below right after client.GetAsync on the id after the uri
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/contacts", id).Result;
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
           contact  = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Contact>().Result;
        }
        return View(contact);

    }
```

And my API method is currently below

```
[ResponseType(typeof(contact))]
    public IHttpActionResult Getcontact(int id)
    {
        contact contact = db.contacts.Find(id);
        if (contact == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(contact);
    }
```

Thanks and I would appreciate any help cant find much on google about people encountering this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the documentation of [GetAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh551757%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), you should pass enum value in your second argument i.e. `HttpCompletionOption enum`.

So, if you want to use int, then you should cast it to `HttpCompletionOption`.
Your code should be :

```
     HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/contacts", 
                                               (HttpCompletionOption)id).Result;
```

It seems that your id is for getting contact, then you should do :

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/contacts/" + id, 
                                          HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead).Result;
```